# Cgroups and docker - misunderstanding

Tags: docker, process, containers

I am trying to understand `docker` in connection to `cgroups` or `cgroups` in connection to `docker`.
I know that `cgroups` make it possible to manage resources for particular process - for example we can assign some piece of `RAM` to `firefox` and some policies on `CPU`.

However, why it is so strong in connection with containers (`docker`) ?
After all, I can also use cgroups (**in the same way**) without docker.  For example, if I launch apacher server within container and without container - in both cases I can control consumed resources.

Moreover, I can also use `cgroups` in connection to `VirtualBox` - I can't magic of docker.

Can you tell me, where I wrong ? I think that I don't understand something.

Answer (score 0):

Docker Uses CGroups, You can use CGroups manually, But docker is not limited to CGroups features:

- Resource limiting
- Prioritization
- Accounting
- Control

Docker Provides:

- Rapid application deployment
- Portability across machines
- Version control and component reuse
- Lightweight footprint and minimal overhead
- Simplified maintenance
- Less Disk foot print using AUFS
- Large Community with lots of pre built images.
- Security
- ...

And the list can go on and on, Not even mentioning manually configuring CGroups, Network namespaces, AUFS, ... can be time consuming with alot of mistakes.